# ChartView, как перерисовать график.

Tags: android, java, диаграммы

Здравствуйте. Предо мной стоит задача нарисовать график по курсу валют.
Всё хорошо, только у меня не получается перегрузить ChartView.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.graphics);
    layout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liner);  
    spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> feat_adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,  buy_sale);
    feat_adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner1.setAdapter(feat_adapter1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            ChartView();

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
    });

    ArrayAdapter<String> feat_adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,  usd_eur);
    feat_adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner2.setAdapter(feat_adapter2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            ChartView();

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
    });
    ChartView();
}
```

Вот функция где я наполняю свою график

```
public void ChartView(){
        mRenderer.setChartTitle("Заголовок");
        mRenderer.setXTitle("Дата (х)");
        mRenderer.setYTitle("Лимит (у)");
        mRenderer.setXAxisMin(dates.get(0)[0].getTime());
        mRenderer.setXAxisMax(dates.get(0)[(dates.get(0).length-1)].getTime());
        mRenderer.setYAxisMin(min());
        mRenderer.setYAxisMax(max()+1);
        mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.GRAY);
        mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        mRenderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });
        mRenderer.setXLabels(10);
        mRenderer.setYLabels(10);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        for(int i = 0; i<NAME_BANK.length; i++)
        {
            TimeSeries series1 = new TimeSeries(NAME_BANK[i]);
            XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            for(int r = 0; r<DATE.length; r++)
            {
                series1.add(dates.get(i)[r], values.get(i)[r]);
            }
            mDataset.addSeries(series1);
            renderer.setColor(colors[i]);
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        }

        if(BarChartView!=null){
            BarChartView.repaint();
        }

        BarChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(GraphicsChart.this, mDataset, mRenderer, "MM/dd");

        layout.addView(BarChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    }
```

После выполнения OnCreate у меня получается вот такая картина
http://clip2net.com/s/1YA77

Как видите  названия банков дублируются, то есть у меня получается 3 раза рисуется график и накладывается друг на друга. Не могу понять почему срабатывает метод setOnItemSelectedListener и как это предотвратить. Подскажите как Сделать что бы картинка не накладывалась??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо либо посадить рисование графика на `ArrayAdapter.onClick()` - что более логично (правда надо создавать свой класс наследующий от `ArrayAdapter`) или же в `onItemSelected()` вставить переменную, которая запоминает последнюю выбранную позицию и если позиция не меняется не рисовать график

Comment: Хорошо а как тогда просто перерисовать View так что бы графики не накладывались друг на друга?

Comment: Создал класс наследник ArrayAdapter. Описал onClick, но реакции при нажатии вообще нет. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: `implements View.OnClickListener` - добавили к наследнику `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: Уже добавил. Но всё равно нет никакой реакции. Я пытался просто вывести тост, но он не выводится.

Comment: Ну что могу сказать - отлаживайте. Это ваш хлеб, не мой же :) Как сделать чтобы адаптер отрабатывал клик - это стандартная задача.

Comment: Задача стандартная, но всё же почему то не получается. Хорошо, спасибо и на том.